# For loop will not work

Tags: java, for-loop

I have looked at numerous examples of for loops and I cannot figure out why mine won't work.  In my program there is a component, viewer and a building class.  I have it set so when you create a new building in the component, you enter x-pos, y-pos, and # of levels.  I want to run the for loop to create each level, but it will not work.  Please help and thanks.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Building
{
    /**number of levels the building has*/
    private int levels;
    private int xLeft;
    private int yTop;
    private int lvls;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Building
     * 
     * @param x x-Coordinate
     * 
     * @param y y-Coordinate
     * 
     * @param levels The number of thevels the building will have
     */
    public Building(int x, int y, int lvls)
    {
        xLeft = x;
        yTop = y;
        levels = lvls;

    }

    /**
     * Draws the building
     * 
     * @param  g2   graphics contex
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
      /**creates one building level*/
      Rectangle body = new Rectangle(xLeft/*X*/, yTop/*Y*/, 100/*Width*/,         100/*Height*/);
      /**creates window inside of building level*/
      Rectangle window = new Rectangle(xLeft+25, yTop+25, 50, 50);
      g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      g2.fill(body);
      g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
      g2.fill(window); 

      /**Creates (levels) number of levels*/
      for(int i = 1; i<=levels; i++)
      {
         /**Adds 100 to y value of body*/
         body.setLocation(xLeft, yTop-100);
         g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
         g2.fill(body);
         window.setLocation(xLeft+25, yTop-75);
         g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
         g2.fill(window);   
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Which value do you pass to the `levels` member?

Comment: you are trying to be a programmer, so you need to be more specific about your condition. what do you mean by it does not work?!!!1

Comment: By it does not work i mean none of the statements inside the loop execute.  I tried putting a System.out.println("test"); in it and that did not print, so the loop is not running at all.

Comment: A value i pass to levels is 5.

Comment: its probably because draw is never being called. There are all sorts of complicated inner workings of how things are drawn on the screen. Put a System.out.println() in the first line of the draw function...I bet you its not being called at all. EDIT: your Building isn't extending anything...so it will never be called unless you explicitly call it. You probably meant to extend something

Comment: using the debugger I found that at all times levels = 5.  during the for loop i = 1.  when it goes back to the top and checks the condition again i = 2.  According to this the loop is working fine, but I am not getting a result.

Comment: I do call the draw method in another class.  I put System.out.println("test"); at the beginning of the draw method and it printed test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the value of `i` inside of your for loop to multiply the value of what you are subtracting from `yTop` each time the loop runs. Right now you are always subtracting `100` from `yTop` as is evident in this line:

```
body.setLocation(xLeft, yTop-100);
```

The problem is that every time the loop runs, you are setting the location to the value of `xLeft` and the value of `yTop - 100`, meaning that you are essentially placing all the levels right on top of eachother. Luckily, we have the value of `i` which increases by 1 each time the loop runs. So we can multiply the `100` we are subtracting from `yTop` by `i` like this:

```
body.setLocation(xLeft, yTop-(100*i));
```

Now, on the first run of the loop, `i` will be `1`. `100*1` is `100`, so `100` will be subtracted from `yTop`. On the second run of the loop, `i` will be increased to `2`. `100*2` is `200`, so `200` will be subtracted from `yTop`. See where I'm going?

For the windows it is a similar idea. Right now you are overlapping all the windows on top of each other. If you change:

```
window.setLocation(xLeft+25, yTop-75);
```

to:

```
window.setLocation(xLeft+25, yTop-(75*i));
```

the windows will no longer overlap.

The window placement code brings up a new problem, however. Because the levels' heights are increasing by 100 and the windows' heights are increasing by only 75, eventually you will have windows which are overlapping two levels at a time. You will see what I mean when you run the program. (There will be a large gap at the top of your building where there are no windows) To fix this, you need to first increase the window height by the same height as the levels, then offset the window by 25 to place it in the center of the level.

This should work better for you:

```
window.setLocation(xLeft+25, yTop-(100*i)+25);
```

I hope this helped!